Pixel 6 constantly restarting, overheating, and draining battery rapidly - how to identify problematic apps?
I’m experiencing a major issue with my Pixel 6, since yesterday morning. The phone keeps restarting on its own and gets very hot. After a restart, it works fine for about a minute, then it becomes extremely laggy, freezes, and restarts again. Additionally, the battery seems to drain very quickly.
Here are some specific details:
Model: Pixel 6
Android Version: 14
Build-No: AP2A.240605.024

Booting into recovery mode (the problem does not occur in this mode)
I suspect that there might be one or more apps causing the system to crash and overheat. However, I am unable to check for software updates or properly manage apps because when I try to open the app list, it loads indefinitely and then Android crashes anyway.

How can I identify and remove apps that might be demanding too much performance and causing these issues within a short time frame after booting? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Is the phone rooted?

Make sure you have backups. Reset your phone and troubleshoot from there.

Nope, the phone wasn't rooted. I've tried to workaround a factory reset. However, I couldn't wait any longer and had to do it. It works now.

For reference: This happened after using Pixel Buds Pro for about 1h, but I don't think there's any connection. I've used them also before and for a longer period.

If possible, connect the phone to a computer with adb, authorize it and collect a bugreport using adb bugreport. This will create a bug report zip.
There are other ways of creating the bugreport, but this is one of the easiest.
Then upload it to battery historian. There is a hosted version of it at https://bathist.ef.lc/. It will tell you which app is using a lot of CPU and how.
Warning: bugreports contain personal data like your Google gmail, possible contact names or other private contents. I don't know who owns the hosted historian instance and what they do with the data.

The statistics didn't help at first. ChatGpt helped me to find the last updated apps. However, it didn't resolve the issue. With adb top I've found the phone has a cpu utilization of 800% (probably because of 8 cores), but none of the app has a high cpu utiliziation.
